# Parameter specified as non-null is null caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dart

After I take a picture and click `checkmark` button on camera interface, I get below exception that leads to app crash:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
```

This exception occurs only if I try to take a picture, not when I select an image from the gallery.

As the exception states that the `data` parameter is being passed as `null` whereas it should be `non-null` and points to the kotlin file function. After researching on this issue, I came to know that I need to pass `?` to the said parameter. (Source : [this](https://snipnyet.com/ojixzzz/5b3ab17077da154922550e92/kotlin-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-parameter-specified/) and [this](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/782)), but now I am getting

```
Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Intent?
```

I have no experience of working with Kotlin so am not sure if that was the correct fix in my case. I would like to know how to fix this issue if anybody has come across an exception like this.

Code below:

```
void _checkCameraPermission() {
    PermissionHandler()
        .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.camera)
        .then((status) {
      if (status == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        getImage(ImageSource.camera);
      } else {
        _askCameraPermission();
      }
    });
  }

  void _askCameraPermission() {
    PermissionHandler()
        .requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.camera]).then(_onStatusRequested);
  }

  void _onStatusRequested(Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> value) {
    final status = value[PermissionGroup.camera];
    if (status == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      getImage(ImageSource.camera);
    }
  }
  Future uploadFile(imageFile) async {
//    String fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    String fileName = "images/" + new Uuid().v4() + ".jpg";
    StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(imageFile);

    await uploadTask.onComplete.then((value) {
      reference.getDownloadURL().then((result) {
        // result is the file URL
        if (result != null) {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });
          onSendMessage(result, 2);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Exception log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402): Process: com.quickcarl.qcflutterpro, PID: 8402
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2343, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.quickcarl.qcflutterpro/com.quickcarl.qcflutterpro.MainActivity}: **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data**
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402):    at com.quickcarl.qcflutterpro.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8402):    ... 9 more
```

MainActivity code:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if(requestCode == VIDEO_SCREEN_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                sendStringMessageToFlutter(data.getStringExtra("roomName"), "completeRoom")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the method in which the error occurs is `onActivityResult()` of `MainActivity`. Post this code please

Comment: Added the code in OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the signature of the `onActivityResult` method as follow:

`override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {}`

This will fix the problem. `data` can be null but you're declaring it as `non-null`

---

EDIT:

Then, in the body of the function, be sure to check for nullability when retrieving the string:

```
if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
   sendStringMessageToFlutter(data?.getStringExtra("roomName") ?: "default_value_when_null", "completeRoom")
}
```

Comment: Great. That worked like charm. Initially I was just checking `null` for `data` in method signature, but wasn't aware of `?` usage inside the method. Good to know this.